# display content in ascending order

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ plugin for custom fields. I successfully displayed pages content on my single page using below code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('picture'); ?>" class="img" width="467" height="395" />
<h2><?php the_field('name'); ?></h2>
<?php the_field('description'); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Where `picture`, `name` and `description` are my custom fields, these 3 fields are assigned to different pages let say with my `about-us`, `contact` and `services` page. Now I need to display them in ascending order means first `contact` content then `about-us` then `services`. Can any one please guide me?

Comment: Have you entered a value in the Order field (page attributes) for each page?  If your Contact page has a value of 1, and About Us has a value of 2, etc then I can show you how to sort by menu order.

Comment: yes I have taken an extra field of name `order` and type `number`

Comment: OK - that is a different query.  Custom fields are stored as meta data in WordPress.  We need a meta query for this.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: For future reference you should be able to use the default WP menu order field for this.  No need for a new custom field for order. The menu order value can be found on the right column of the page editor under Page Attributes.

Comment: oh I see, thanx again @jdm2112.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with many things, there is more than one way to accomplish this.  A simple method is to pass an `order` and `orderby` value to the query.  I believe the most efficient way to do this sort on a specific page is with `pre_get_posts` but rather than over-complicate this for you, the simple method instead.

You'll create an "arguments" variable and pass these to a custom query.  You're code would then look like this:

```
<?php 
// These are the arguments for the custom query
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        );

// Instantiate query 
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('picture'); ?>" class="img" width="467" height="395" />
<h2><?php the_field('name'); ?></h2>
<?php
    the_field('description');

  endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```

This will sort your based on the menu order.  There are many other options for sorting available.   See the Codex entry for WP_Query class:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

EDIT - Meta query option based on info from OP. `$args` variable now contains `orderby` and `meta_key` values.

```
<?php 
// These are the arguments for the custom query
$args = array(
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'order'
        );

// Instantiate query 
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<img src="<?php the_field('picture'); ?>" class="img" width="467" height="395" />
<h2><?php the_field('name'); ?></h2>
<?php
    the_field('description');

  endwhile; 
endif; 
?>
```